# Passing binary data through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking, httpwebrequest

Using .Net, I want to pass some binary data(some serialized objects) through an HttpWebRequest.

Can I just put it on the request stream, or do I need to encode it into a base64 string?

I mean if i have:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1000];
GetSomeStrangeData(data);
```

Do I need to Use Convert.ToBase64String or can I just write it to the stream from HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ?

---

for posterity :

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx

http://www.wireshark.org/

http://www.fiddler2.com

Comment: Why did you create a 1000-byte array and then discard it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders because i was careless writing the question. I've edited

Comment: Does "some serialized objects" mean `new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(...)`? Do not store such data or send it to another machine. The .NET binary serialization format changes between hardware and .NET version.

Comment: @DourHighArch that's only true for .NET 1.1 , Read the documentation in the MSDN about binary serialization, it should be upgrade-able.
other then that, that isn't what I'm sending...

Comment: @Hellfrost, really? Provide a link and I'll +1 your question.

Comment: 1.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.80).aspx  
2.http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/netframeworkclasses/article.php/c9297

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write your data to a stream via the `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream`, you will be sending pure binary data without any transformation to base64.  You will have to parse the data on the receiving end as a binary stream.

As a side note, I would also always steer away from base64 when sending data across a network because it will increase your bandwidth to transfer the data.  For every 3 bytes that you convert to base64 will come out 4.  So you have a 33% overhead for all of your data.

EDIT: Going into a little more depth here for Hellfrost. The `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` allows you lower level access to the stream which in-turn allows you to send binary data over the connection.  If you are trying to send the data to a web-server, I would suggest you looking into post-data and `multipart/form-data`. You can read more about it here: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/566462/708155)

Comment: here too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx
since HTTP is intended for text this means one need to convert his data into a textual representation...

Comment: The HTTP protocol is majorly used on websites to transfer text data, but at the point that it is transmitted to you, the data is just binary data.  I updated my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Streams read and write binary. GetRequestStream returns a Stream.

Comment: Will writing my array to that specific stream, will just end up writing the buffer into the network stream, or will it be converted to base64 ?

Comment: Streams just read and write binary. They're the lowest-level I/O abstraction. They don't convert anything.

Comment: That's nonsense... a LOT of stream object manipulate data transfered to them e.g. Compression... Since raw binary data like the value 0 (not the text) is problematic with HTTP, I would expect it to be converted

Comment: The Stream.Write interface takes a byte buffer. It is up to the stream implementation to decide what it wants to do with it - whether it wants to transform it in some manner, or send it as is. So yes, a particular stream implementation might transform data. However, the stream that you get back from GetRequestStream() does not.

Comment: I needed some idea of what will pass on the wire, and i hoped doing that, without reading the HTTP RFC and sitting for an evening or two with Wireshark...